# Should loaded images and text be stored in memory or retrieved each time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app has various pins that drop onto a map and when you click on the pins you get more information about this entity.

Each time you click on the entity it retrieves the information from a web service.  Should I only retrieve this information once and store it in memory or should I retrieve it each time that page loads?

It's a small about of text and 3 small images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just 3 small images and some text that will not change i would probably cache them in the application instead of retriving them over and over, it will provide a better user expirience in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Also I have a Core Data application that uses images...
I tried both methods but I chose to retrieve it every time because for my goal is the best practice. However this method causes me to write some code and a lot of if and else!
How Daniel said, cache each image can be a better solution for your problem because if an user would like to retrieve these images from internet but the connections isn't fast, he'll wait a lot of time...